# Starting created service using sc.exe throws error: "[SC] StartService FAILED with error 129."

Tags: windows, service, driver

I create the service using following commands: `sc create MyService 
 binpath= "C:\Path\MyDriver.sys"` and the returned message is: `[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`, but once I want to start this service using: `sc start MyService` I get the error: `[SC] StartService FAILED with error 129.`. Have you any idea how to fix this error and start service properly? I've seen [this](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/11618224/sc-exe-error-129), but there's no proper answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much! You should add an answer instead of this comment. :)

Comment: You meant mark your comment as answer anyhow? Anyway, now I get the error 1275, which means, that drivers wasn't loaded because of Patch Guard + Windows shows message about unsigned driver... I tried enable test mode (cmd.exe -> "bcdedit /set testsigning off" and reboot), but the error still exist, just the Windows message doesn't show. I thought Visual Studio signs my drivers...

Comment: I won't add your answer, do it please, you helped me. I'll just disable digital signature validating through GPEdit.

Comment: Ok, it should be `bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON` (not "off") to enable test mode.

Comment: That was just typo, meant "on" instead off "off". "Test mode" watermark shows at right bottom corner, so everything should be ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error code 129 is `ERROR_CHILD_NOT_COMPLETE` (i.e. the application cannot be run in Win32 mode). You created a user-mode service since the default is `type= own` (i.e. `SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS` when calling WinAPI `CreateService`). However, you're trying to run a kernel-mode driver, which should be `type= kernel` (i.e. `SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER`).